# Implementing Arp Sweep

Tags: java, c, libpcap, jpcap

I have been playing with libpcap/jpcap. Implementing a arp sweeper. I send a request for all ip's in the block to the broadcast address and read replies. Now i can't think of a way to exit from the listening function. Now i wait 2 secs and assume ever client responded but this just seems dirty. Can anyone recommend a logic to determine if the scan is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's taking more than 2 seconds then there is something very wrong with the network. This tool defaults at 250 ms: http://linux-ip.net/sw/arpsweep/arpsweep.8.html